# XSLT Child Node Count

Tags: xslt

I need to Set GeneralErrorMessage to "Success" in the following XML through XSLT if Failures Child Node Count is 0.Please help me with XSLT snippet.

```
<DeleteResponse xmlns="http://schemas.xyz.com/xyzEnterprise/Services/ProjectService3/2012/08">
      <DeleteResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.xyz.com/xyzEnterprise/OpenSuite/OpenSuiteResult/2010/01/01" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Failures xmlns:b="http://schemas.xyz.com/xyzEnterprise/OpenSuite/OpenSuiteStatus/2010/01/01" i:nil="true"/>
        <a:GeneralErrorMessage i:nil="true"/>
        <a:Successes xmlns:b="http://schemas.xyz.com/xyzEnterprise/OpenSuite/OpenSuiteStatus/2010/01/01">
          <b:OpenSuiteStatus xmlns:c="http://schemas.xyz.com/xyzEnterprise/OpenSuite/ProjectStatus/2012/08" i:type="c:ProjectStatus2">
            <b:Code i:nil="true"/>
            <b:ErrorMessage i:nil="true"/>
            <b:SourceIndex>0</b:SourceIndex>
            <c:Dto xmlns:d="http://schemas.xyz.com/xyzEnterprise/OpenSuite/Dtos/ProjectDto2/2012/08">
              <d:ActualFinishDate i:nil="true"/>
              <d:ActualStartDate i:nil="true"/>
              <d:CalendarKey i:nil="true"/>
              <d:Description i:nil="true"/>
              <d:Duration i:nil="true"/>
              <d:EnterProgress i:nil="true"/>
              <d:EntryDate i:nil="true"/>
              <d:FatherKey i:nil="true"/>
              <d:IsMilestone i:nil="true"/>
              <d:IsTicketable i:nil="true"/>
              <d:Key>key://2/$Plan/13795</d:Key>
              <d:LifecycleAdminUserKey i:nil="true"/>
              <d:Notes i:nil="true"/>
              <d:PercentComplete i:nil="true"/>
              <d:Place i:nil="true"/>
              <d:ScheduleFinishDate i:nil="true"/>
              <d:ScheduleStartDate i:nil="true"/>
              <d:WorkId i:nil="true"/>
              <d:WorkStatusKey i:nil="true"/>
            </c:Dto>
          </b:OpenSuiteStatus>
        </a:Successes>
        <a:Warnings xmlns:b="http://schemas.xyz.com/xyzEnterprise/OpenSuite/OpenSuiteStatus/2010/01/01" i:nil="true"/>
      </DeleteResult>
    </DeleteResponse>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? Please post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Write a stylesheet that contains an identity template rule to copy elements by default, and then add the rule

```
<xsl:template match="a:GeneralErrorMessage[count(//a:Failures/*)=0]">
 <xsl:copy>Success</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="a:GeneralErrorMessage[count(//a:Failures/*)=0]">
     <xsl:copy>Success</xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: is not compiling. Are there any namespace conflicts?

Comment: Obviously if you use the prefix "a" in your stylesheet then you need to declare it.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xyz.com/xyzEnterprise/OpenSuite/OpenSuiteResult/2010/01/01"><xsl:template match="@*|node()"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template> <xsl:template match="a:GeneralErrorMessage[count(//a:Failures/*)=0]"> <xsl:copy>Success</xsl:copy> </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: The SO convention is to mark the answer as accepted, rather than to post a comment saying thanks. It makes it easier for anyone coming here to find the right answer to the question quickly.